# allow to register and login with Firestore

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have this following database in Firestore
[image]

The security rule of the database is the following:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{users} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

I can not register into the database, because of the security rules.

The flutter code is the following:

```
try {
      final newUser =
      await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      DataBaseService(uid: newUser.user?.uid)
      .addUserData(
      userName: userName,
      );
      widget.registered();
      nav.pop();
      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      setState(() {
      _hideSpinner = true;
      });
```

What should be the security rule to let the user to register?

Comment: Please show your code (`addUserData()` too) so we can help

Answer (score 0):

Just add `allow write: if request.auth != null` under `allow read` line.